# Retain checked status of checkbox and add new values to check box

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox

I have unique query, 
I want the checkboxes to remain checked after ajax makes the call to DB and gets some extra values.
Suppose there are four values checked before ajax call and after ajax call to DB there are 6 values out of which four are same values as checked ones. I need the four of the initial values to be checked and other two new values to be unchecked.
Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Many ways actually.. But those are applied on the code.. Will you mind haring your code ?

Comment: can you let me know the ways to do, its not possible for me to share the code

Comment: That's simple, just add two more checkboxes in the callback function of you AJAX request. Post the code you have so far to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: if i do so, then the previous checked values wont be in checked status. I need to manually recheck them once again